# I tried to remove null from my Hashset using Set.remove(null). But it is not actually working. What could i have been wrong here.?

Tags: java, list, null, hashset

Below is my code. I tried to remove null references from List and also from Set. Still i could see Null coming up in the printed Hashset. Where could i be wrong?

```
public boolean checkStickySession(Map<String,List<String>> map1){
            List<String> sessionList = map1.get("sessionId");
            sessionList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
            Set<String> sessionSet = new HashSet<String>(sessionList);
            boolean status=false;
            sessionSet.remove(null);
            logger.info("sessionSet::"+sessionSet);
            if(sessionSet != null && sessionSet.size()==1){
                status = true;
            }
            return status;
        }
```

Comment: both should remove `null` from either the `List` or the `Set`. Your problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: I would do `sessionList.remove(null)` but it should work either way. Once it has been removed from the list you shouldn't need to also remove it from the set.

Comment: `sessionList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));` throws a NPE in my tests, could this be part of your problem?

Comment: Just to be on a safe side. Removing it from both the list and set. Nope NPE comes when we have some immutable copy. I dont think here it isnt case. I think peter lawrey is correct. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you have the String `"null"` which prints the same but is not the same reference. If you step through the code in your debugger you will be able to see the difference.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("null");
list.add(null);
System.out.println(list); // prints [null, null]
assert list.size() == 2;
list.remove(null);
assert list.size() == 1;

list.remove(null); // can't remove the "null" this way.
assert list.size() == 1;

System.out.println(list); // prints [null]
list.remove("null");
assert list.size() == 0;
```

Comment: Your answer looks valid for me. I will give it a try and let you know :)